# I forget the github passphrases. I change the SSH key on GitHub... But still doesn't work

Tags: github, ssh-keys

Now, I have a new Key on GitHub and a new passphrase... But:

`ssh -T git@github.com`

Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
Permission denied (publickey).

Ubuntu 12.10
I follow: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

Comment: Are you sure the (correct) key was correctly added? I just added a key on MacOS X, and the ssh line worked right away.

Comment: Also verified to work for me on Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: I think so, I'm use xclip and eliminate previous keys from .shh (all the previous files on the folder)
Looks to my like I have a new key, but some in the system it's remembering or looking for the previous key with the forgotten pass ? And I don't have any idea of where it's.

Comment: Can you run `ssh-keygen -l -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa` and verify that you have the same fingerprint on a key on github?

Answer (score 0):

try to add `SSH_AUTH_SOCK=0` before the ssh command.
like `SSH_AUTH_SOCK=0 ssh user@server`

if it work for you add `SSH_AUTH_SOCK=0` to your .bashrc file.
regards

Answer (score 0):

Read your **ssh key**:
    cat  ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

Copy them and paste to "**SSH KEY**" in **Github**.
Then add the new ssh key to let the machine recognize:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

And the problem will be solved.